# SonarQube import checkstyle fails: JRubyFacade

Tags: sonarqube, jruby, checkstyle, sonarqube5.1

The goals is to take SonarWay and extend it with a custom Checkstyle configuration.

---

System:
OS: `RHEL 6.6 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64`

Sonarqube: `5.1`

Checkstyle plugin: `2.3 (latest)`

java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

---

The Checkstyle.xml (copied in steps, so might contain duplications):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<!--
    This configuration file was written by the eclipse-cs plugin configuration editor
-->
<!--
    Checkstyle-Configuration: Copy of Techem Style
    Description: none
-->
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="allowMissingPropertyJavadoc" value="true"/>
      <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocType"/>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
      <property name="severity" value="info"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocStyle">
      <property name="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ConstantName"/>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName"/>
    <module name="LocalVariableName"/>
    <module name="MemberName"/>
    <module name="MethodName"/>
    <module name="PackageName"/>
    <module name="ParameterName"/>
    <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
    <module name="TypeName"/>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
    <module name="IllegalImport"/>
    <module name="RedundantImport"/>
    <module name="UnusedImports"/>
    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="severity" value="info"/>
      <property name="max" value="180"/>
      <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodLength"/>
    <module name="ParameterNumber"/>
    <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad"/>
    <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="tokens" value="BNOT,DEC,DOT,INC,LNOT,UNARY_MINUS,UNARY_PLUS"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>
    <module name="OperatorWrap"/>
    <module name="ParenPad">
      <property name="tokens" value="CTOR_CALL,METHOD_CALL,RPAREN,SUPER_CTOR_CALL"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround"/>
    <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
    <module name="RedundantModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks"/>
    <module name="EmptyBlock"/>
    <module name="LeftCurly"/>
    <module name="NeedBraces"/>
    <module name="RightCurly"/>
    <module name="EmptyStatement"/>
    <module name="EqualsHashCode"/>
    <module name="IllegalInstantiation"/>
    <module name="InnerAssignment"/>
    <module name="MagicNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="info"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
    <module name="RedundantThrows">
      <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression"/>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn"/>
    <module name="DesignForExtension">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FinalClass"/>
    <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor"/>
    <module name="InterfaceIsType"/>
    <module name="VisibilityModifier"/>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
    <module name="FinalParameters">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TodoComment">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="UpperEll"/>
    <module name="FinalParameters">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MultipleVariableDeclarations"/>
  </module>
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="Translation"/>
  <module name="FileLength"/>
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="SeverityMatchFilter">
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

What I did:

1. Add the checkstyle plugin to sonarqube
2. Go to quality profiles
3. Create a new profile and select the Checkstyle.xml
4. Click on create

At this point it fails with a generic "something went wrong" message in the web-interface. The log file shows the following:

```
2015.07.24 11:54:47 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://[url]:9000/profiles/create
The definition of the profile 'null' (language 'null') contains multiple occurrences of the 'checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.FinalParametersCheck' rule. The plugin which declares this profile should fix this.
```

What can I do to get my rules imported? What other information can I provide?

Answer (score 1):

This `Checkstyle.xml` contains a duplication:

```
<module name="FinalParameters">
  <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
  <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
</module>
```

appears twice in the `TreeWalker` module.

If you remove this duplication, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

And do you know what the problem is here? What is the reason that this file cannot be imported in SonarQube 5.1.2 with CheckStyle 2.3?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
      <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocType">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
      <property name="authorFormat" value="^.../[^,]+(,\s.../[^,]+)*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
      <property name="scope" value="public"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocStyle"/>
    <module name="ConstantName"/>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
      <property name="format" value="^[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MemberName"/>
    <module name="MethodName"/>
    <module name="PackageName"/>
    <module name="ParameterName"/>
    <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
    <module name="TypeName"/>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
    <module name="IllegalImport"/>
    <module name="RedundantImport"/>
    <module name="UnusedImports"/>
    <module name="MethodLength"/>
    <module name="ParameterNumber"/>
    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="max" value="180"/>
      <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad"/>
    <module name="MethodParamPad"/>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter"/>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore"/>
    <module name="OperatorWrap"/>
    <module name="ParenPad"/>
    <module name="TypecastParenPad"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter"/>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
      <property name="tokens" value="ASSIGN,BAND,BAND_ASSIGN,BOR,BOR_ASSIGN,BSR,BSR_ASSIGN,BXOR,BXOR_ASSIGN,COLON,DIV,DIV_ASSIGN,EQUAL,GE,GT,LAND,LCURLY,LE,LITERAL_ASSERT,LITERAL_CATCH,LITERAL_DO,LITERAL_ELSE,LITERAL_FINALLY,LITERAL_FOR,LITERAL_IF,LITERAL_RETURN,LITERAL_SYNCHRONIZED,LITERAL_TRY,LITERAL_WHILE,LOR,LT,MINUS,MINUS_ASSIGN,MOD,MOD_ASSIGN,NOT_EQUAL,PLUS,PLUS_ASSIGN,QUESTION,SL,SLIST,SL_ASSIGN,SR,SR_ASSIGN,STAR,STAR_ASSIGN,LITERAL_ASSERT,TYPE_EXTENSION_AND,WILDCARD_TYPE"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ModifierOrder"/>
    <module name="RedundantModifier">
      <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF,ANNOTATION_FIELD_DEF"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks"/>
    <module name="EmptyBlock">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LeftCurly"/>
    <module name="NeedBraces"/>
    <module name="RightCurly"/>
    <module name="AvoidInlineConditionals"/>
    <module name="EmptyStatement"/>
    <module name="EqualsHashCode"/>
    <module name="HiddenField">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalInstantiation"/>
    <module name="InnerAssignment">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MagicNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault"/>
    <module name="RedundantThrows">
      <property name="suppressLoadErrors" value="true"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression"/>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn"/>
    <module name="DesignForExtension">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FinalClass"/>
    <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor"/>
    <module name="InterfaceIsType"/>
    <module name="VisibilityModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <property name="packageAllowed" value="true"/>
      <property name="protectedAllowed" value="true"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle"/>
    <module name="FinalParameters">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TodoComment"/>
    <module name="UpperEll"/>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace"/>
    <module name="MissingOverride"/>
  </module>
  <module name="JavadocPackage">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile"/>
  <module name="Translation"/>
  <module name="FileLength"/>
  <module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="^\s*@[A-Za-z]+(\([^\)]*\))?\s+[^\(].+$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Do not use inline annotations"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="format" value="\([^)]*@[^\s]+\s\s+.*\)"/>
    <property name="message" value="Use single space after inline annotation"/>
  </module>
</module>
```